# Does dockerd support WatchdogSec sd_notify health checks?

Tags: docker, systemd, freeze, watchdog

We've been having issues where the Docker daemon will occasionally stop responding on one of our Kubernetes systems, but Systemd still thinks the service is running:

```
systemctl status docker
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2019-04-15 20:40:57 UTC; 3 months 22 days ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
 Main PID: 1281 (dockerd)
    Tasks: 1409
   Memory: 31.0G
      CPU: 5d 17h 3min 4.758s
   CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
           ├─ 1281 /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd://
...
```

There isn't anything in the `journalctl -u docker` or syslog files to indicate what the issue is, but the Docker daemon no longer responds to requests (`docker ps` just hangs). We are currently using the `17.03.2~ce-0~ubuntu-xenial` package for Ubuntu 16.04, which has the following service unit:

```
cat /lib/systemd/system/docker.service
[Unit]
Description=Docker Application Container Engine
Documentation=https://docs.docker.com
After=network.target docker.socket firewalld.service
Requires=docker.socket

[Service]
Type=notify
# the default is not to use systemd for cgroups because the delegate issues still
# exists and systemd currently does not support the cgroup feature set required
# for containers run by docker
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd://
ExecReload=/bin/kill -s HUP $MAINPID
LimitNOFILE=1048576
# Having non-zero Limit*s causes performance problems due to accounting overhead
# in the kernel. We recommend using cgroups to do container-local accounting.
LimitNPROC=infinity
LimitCORE=infinity
# Uncomment TasksMax if your systemd version supports it.
# Only systemd 226 and above support this version.
TasksMax=infinity
TimeoutStartSec=0
# set delegate yes so that systemd does not reset the cgroups of docker containers
Delegate=yes
# kill only the docker process, not all processes in the cgroup
KillMode=process

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I noticed that even though it is a `Type=notify` service, there isn't a `WatchdogSec=` defined in the service unit.

Does the Docker daemon support setting a watchdog timeout for sd_notify based health checks?

Comment: There are external methods of enabling this like https://github.com/balena-os/healthdog-rs/ that wraps the daemon to add Watchdog support, but I'm curious if it can be enabled on the stock daemon

Answer (score 0):

**No**, currently the [components/engine/cmd/dockerd/daemon_linux.go](https://github.com/docker/docker-ce/blob/master/components/engine/cmd/dockerd/daemon_linux.go) file only implements [systemdDaemon.SdNotifyReady](https://github.com/coreos/go-systemd/blob/fd7a80b32e1fc73e890fde45604ed5009dc817a3/daemon/sdnotify.go#L32) to notify Systemd when the process has started. For watchdog support it would have to use something like [SdWatchdogEnabled](https://github.com/coreos/go-systemd/blob/fd7a80b32e1fc73e890fde45604ed5009dc817a3/daemon/sdnotify.go#L32) to continually send `SdNotifyWatchdog = "WATCHDOG=1"` notifications.

If you try and set `WatchdogSec=60s` on the docker.service file it will kill and restart the service because the daemon doesn't send the required notifications.

```
systemctl status docker.service
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2019-08-08 02:09:52 UTC; 50s ago

systemctl status docker.service
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: deactivating (stop-sigabrt) (Result: watchdog) since Thu 2019-08-08 02:10:02 UTC; 45ms ago

systemctl status docker.service
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (start) since Thu 2019-08-08 02:10:04 UTC; 777ms ago

# Log entries:
Aug 08 02:09:14 kam1 systemd[1]: Starting Docker Application Container Engine...
Aug 08 02:09:15 kam1 systemd[1]: Started Docker Application Container Engine.
Aug 08 02:10:15 kam1 systemd[1]: docker.service: Watchdog timeout (limit 60s)!
Aug 08 02:10:15 kam1 systemd[1]: docker.service: Killing process 12383 (dockerd) with signal SIGABRT.
Aug 08 02:10:16 kam1 systemd[1]: docker.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT
Aug 08 02:10:16 kam1 systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'watchdog'.
Aug 08 02:10:18 kam1 systemd[1]: docker.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Aug 08 02:10:18 kam1 systemd[1]: docker.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 3.
Aug 08 02:10:18 kam1 systemd[1]: Stopped Docker Application Container Engine.
Aug 08 02:10:18 kam1 systemd[1]: Starting Docker Application Container Engine...
```